# Needs help in database query

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables Table1 and Table2.  There are 10 fields in Table1 and 9 fields in Table2.  There is one common column in both the tables i.e. AdateTime.  This column saves unix time stamp of user actions.  I want to display records from both the tables as a single result but sorting must me according to AdateTime.  Recent action should be display first.  Sometimes many recent actions in Table1 but few in Table2.  Vice versa is also possible.  So I want to fetch combine result set from both the tables using single query.  I am using PHP MySQL.

Comment: do you want all the rows from Table1 and Table2 or just those rows that have a matching Adatetime value?

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your post.  Yes I want all the rows from both the tables i.e. so when table1 has recent record query fetches table2 null records and if table2 has recent record query fetches table1 null records.  I want to order this result set according to recent time.  We have common field ADateTime in both the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) with an inline view. So something like

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,AdateTime
from
(
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,AdateTime from Table1
UNION ALL
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,null as col9,AdateTime from Table2
) t
order by t.Adatetime desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Lets try out your solution.  Are you sure we can perform Union on tables who have different number of columns?

Comment: It is possible. Though you'll need to put a dummy column so that the number of columns from the Table1 select matches the number of columns from the Table2 select. That's why there is a 'null as col9' in the select from Table2.

Comment: Thanks Tom, your solutions seems to be working.  Just need to test with few records.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.AdateTime = t2.AdateTime
ORDER BY t1.AdateTime
```

or (if tables are not related)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ADateTime, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1
     UNION 
     SELECT ADateTime, col1, col2, 1 AS col3, NULL AS col4 FROM table2) t2
ORDER by ADateTime
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I read that UNION is possible when number of columns are same in both the tables.  Is it true? because in this case we have different number of columns.  Thanks a lot .

Comment: @NareshChauhan: you're right. If you have different columns, read my edited answer :)

Comment: I just tried this query but it shows me #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias kind of error in phpMyadmin.  Any idea?  Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: I tried modified query but this time it shows syntax error near 't2) t3 ORDER by createDateTime'.  Any clue?

Comment: "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns".  May be we need to fill dummy null fields like Tom Mac said here.  What you say?

Comment: @NareshChauhan: the number of columns MUST be the same in every SELECT used in UNION, so yes, maybe you need some dummy column. If you look at my query I've always udes same columns...

Comment: Yes, dummy null column works.  Thanks a lot for your time.  My real struggle starts now because I 3 left outer joins in both the tables. :) thanks a lot for your prompt reply

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.  Can you explain again?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it. you just need to join these 2 tables with a join condition. when the join condition matches for a row only that row ll be displayed then further you can write the Code for any operation. use order by AdateTime

```
select t1.column_1234,t2.column_1234
     from t1 table1 , t2 table2
     where t1.matching_column = t2.matching_column
     order by t1.AdateTime;

t1.matching_column And t2.matching_column are the Primary And Foreign keys for these tables (Matching Column)
```